# Sonarqube: use multiple custom quality profiles for a single multilanguage project...?

Tags: javascript, java, groovy, sonarqube

Maybe this is already a feature of Sonarqube, but I can’t find evidence of it anywhere.  We have projects that contain java, javascript, and groovy code.  I can analyze each language separately, or I can do a multi-language analysis if I use the default quality profiles for each language. But I can’t figure out how to use three custom profiles (java, javascript, and groovy) for the same project.  Is it possible?

I’m currently running Sonarqube 4.3.3, and using the maven to build and analyze the projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to assign the project to those non-default profiles. Someone with admin rights on the project can do that, and of course global admins can too.

Comment: Yes, that will work, but I suppose there's no way to do this from the command line (I know I didn't ask that specifically in the original post).  I currently use the -Dsonar.profile switch, but that only seems to accept a single argument.

Comment: In fact @Glenn, that parameter (which is deprecated) is from the days before multi-language analysis. You'll have to use the GUI.